# Processing files in sub directories with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

We have multiple admin directories inside that multiple files, I want to use multhreading in following way for processing files. 
1)  There will be a single thread for each admin directories.
2)  The each admin assigned thread will be process the files sequentially in sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I'll get you started.

What you want is to do is to use an ExecutorService, which will manage the threads for you.

First create a class that implements Runnable, with a member variable of a java.io.File, which will point to the subdirectory you are going to process  Inside the class's run method, do whatever is you want to do for each subdirectory.

Then create your main class, which will first create an ExecutorService, then interrogate your top level directory to find the subdirectories.  For each subdirectory, create a new instance of your class above and ask the ExecutorService to execute it.

Here's a good example:  https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/executorservice/java-executorservice-example-tutorial/